# Tomcat авторизация с Servlet3

Tags: servlet, jsp, auth

Пользователь заходит на станицу `http://mysite.ru/path/qwerty`
Если он не авторизован его кидает на `http://mysite.ru/path/login`, там он вводит логин, пароль и жмет Войти.

Как после входа переадресовать его обратно на `http://mysite.ru/path/qwerty`?

Вход выполняется через:
`request.login(user, pass);`

web.xml

> ```
> <login-config>
>     <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
>     <form-login-config>
>         <form-login-page>/login</form-login-page>
>         <form-error-page>/login</form-error-page>
>     </form-login-config>
> </login-config>
> ```

Comment: @fba, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

При переходе на страницу логина дополнительно тащите с собой параметр - источник перехода, значением которого будет URL страницы. После успешного логина просто выполните переход по этому URL.